# When does phone locking occur and who locks the phone?

Tags: sim-unlocking

For some specific info, I bought a phone from Amazon in 2018:

> Samsung Galaxy S9 Plus (6.2", Single SIM) 128GB SM-G965F (GSM Only, No
> CDMA) Factory Unlocked LTE Smartphone (Midnight Black) - International
> Version

After receiving this phone 5 years ago, I then drove to a T-Mobile store so they could set up service for me.  Now 5 years later, I am changing carriers.  My last payment to T-Mobile was January 18, 2023, so I assume my service expired February 18, 2023 which was three months ago.  The new carrier I would like to have is Mint.  I have purchased a Mint sim card and inserted it into my phone.  I called a Mint technician with the Mint sim card.  The tech told me my phone is locked.  I later called a T-Mobile tech with another phone.  They seem to not have my account anymore.

My questions then are about phone locking.  If I bought an unlocked phone off of Amazon, would T-Mobile have locked the phone when I got T-Mobile service?  Should Mint be able to just activate the sim card and get it to work?

I am confused about the idea of phone locking.  Is this something that is done to phones that are purchased from a carrier, but not done to phones that are purchased from a manufacturer? Is this something the carrier must do to activate service, and then they must unlock when service expires?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Perhaps [Does putting an unlocked phone on a no-contract plan lock the phone in any way?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179822/44325) might be related or possibly duplicate.